# Restoring jQuery objects after .detach()

Tags: jquery, detach

I'm going in circles on this one. I have a list of houses. I want to remove houses that don't match chosen criteria. Each house is contained in an li tag.

I thought I could make a jQuery Object of all the li tags on the page, manipulate it, remove the current li tags from the page and append the new list.

But I'm stuck...

```
<ul id="items">
<li id="p123">Property 1</li>
<li id="p456">Property 2</li>
<li id="p789">Property 3</li>
</ul>


var $j_object = $("li");
var clone = $j_object.clone();

$('li').detach();

itemToShow = '#p456';

// three options to restore list item
$(itemToShow).appendTo($("#items"));

$($j_object[itemToShow]).appendTo($("#items"));

$($clone[itemToShow]).appendTo($("#items"));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cc01euf2/

Comment: use `console.log(object)` and the console (f12 in chrome) to see what each variable contains.

Comment: And the jquery method you are looking for is `$().find()`. `$j_object.find(itemToShow).appendTo($("#items"))`

Comment: @slicedtoad I've updated the fiddle with console commands [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cc01euf2/3/) but I'm not sure how to access the li tags from there. I can see the contents of the objects but I can't work out how to append them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have a **collection** of jquery objects via:

```
var $j_object = $("li");
```

Essentially, this is an array like:

```
['li#p123', 'li#p456', 'li#p789'] //made up of elements, not strings obviously
```

To select a single element from this array, you have to use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). This does the same thing as `find` but it searches the top layer only. Whereas `find` searches the descendants of each element in the collection.

So,

```
$j_object.filter('#p456').appendTo('#items');
```

Will get the `#p456` element and append it to `#items`.

Also, note that `$j_object` still references `#p456` even after you append it.

Demo of adding and removing: http://jsfiddle.net/2Lyudrsj/1/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of detaching the elements from the DOM, you may want to consider just hiding/showing them if they do or don't match your criteria.

```
$('#items li').each(function() {
    if($(this).html().indexOf('Property 2') > -1) { 
        $(this).hide();
    } else {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dfdq49j4/2/

Comment: Thanks... normally I would use show/hide but this project is using Block Grid in Foundation and the CSS makes the result with show/ hide look like a bad tetris player.